# Set max participants separately for male and female

Tags: civievent

Is it possible to configure the maximum number of participants at an event separately for male and female attendees?

We are using webform to handle registrations for our summer camps and want to limit registrations to say 25 boys and 25 girls. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't think of a simple way. Have you considered running them as to separate events as far as registrations go.

Comment: that's a good answer pete

Comment: thanks. had considered separate events and looks like that is the only 'out-of-the-box' option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use civicrm forms, you can do it using price sets and creating 2 options : male and female and limiting the amount of people per item.

Comment: That sounds like a good option to consider

Answer (score 2):

I would do this by writing a little bit of custom code. It would need to:

- Implement hook_form_alter and add a validation callback to the webform
- Look up the event participants using the civicrm api
- Only allow the submission to be completed if there are < n number of people with the given gender already enrolled.

Answer (score 2):

I will take the comment from petednz and coleman as the answer that there is no easy way to do this 'out-of-the-box' except to create separate events for male and female attendees.